# Will the Android Device Manager app installed by one user enforce the policies for another user of the same device?

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to Android Development. I am developing an app which will disable the camera for security reasons. When the device owner logs in as User A, he activates the app which will disable the camera. When the  device owner logs in as User B/Guest then the camera is enabled. But I don't want the camera to be enabled for them. Is this possible if I design the app as a Device Manager? Will the policies enforced by the Device Manager app work across different users of the same device?

Answer (score 0):

Look, so far I know that System keeps users running. just switch between them.

See: [Supporting Multiple User](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html)

> User. Each user is intended to be used by a different physical person.
>   Each user has distinct application data and some unique settings, as
>   well as a user interface to explicitly switch between users. **A user
>   can run in the background when another user is active**; the system
>   manages shutting down users to conserve resources...

So that would explain why permissions are shared between users. I would recommend you to check if current front loggeg-in user is the owner.Then allow camera, otherwise disable it.

You can obtain whether user is owner(admin) by: [Android UserManager: Check if user is owner (admin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749504/android-usermanager-check-if-user-is-owner-admin)

Comment: Thanks @maher. Will try and let you know.