# Is there a way to detect whether current profile is a Guest or not on Android?

Tags: android

Starting from Lollipop and newer versions Android supports multiple user profiles on one device. Besides, the current profile may be a Guest. Android SDK provides some Intents to detect the switch between profiles.

But I need to check current profile type. Is there a way to obtain this information, but awaiting for manual profile switch?

Comment: Possibly useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448131/2911458

Comment: hm, it looks like a suitable solution. Thank you! I'll try it soon and check.