# Android: Check if Current User is a guest

Tags: android, usermanager

I had a read through UserManager and UserHandle docs and couldn't find any method which would return a boolean answering the question. Anyone have an idea how to determine this?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749504/android-usermanager-check-if-user-is-owner-admin/15448131#15448131

Comment: @Akki, this is if user is owner, not if they are guest. There is no const for guest so this method does not work

Comment: I don't think there is any direct method that could fulfil your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UserInfo* class has “*isGuest()*” method returning a Boolean and *UserManager.getUsers()* returns a list, of UserInfo type. BUT, all these methods are hidden and not supported for 3rd party apps.

Additionally, the *getUsers()* method requires “*android.Manifest.permission.MANAGE_USERS*” permission, which is meant for only system (or any apps that have the platform key, or if your app only runs on Android emulator, as it gets a default platform key). So, even if you find any way to sign your application with the platform signature, it would definitely break on one or more Android versions.

Although You can try with reflection to get the access for getUsers() like below:

```
UserManager manager = (UserManager)getSystemService(USER_SERVICE);
Method method = manager.getClass().getMethod("getUsers", null);
Object users = method.invoke(manager, null);
```

But, again there seem no guarantees you will get what you want here.

Comment: Reflection no longer works on Android 28+

Comment: That is what, I tried to say with "there seem no guarantees you will get what you want here". I am also looking for a solution to this, in case possible.